# Does lever needs gravitation to work?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Simple question - Does lever needs gravitation force to work or it just needs fulcrum and could work in vacuum as well?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Unfortunately this question is considered low quality as currently phrased.  Please see this [help page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some advice on how to edit your question to improve it.

Comment: An atmosphere is not dependent on gravity and gravity does not imply an atmosphere. They are independent. For example the ISS has an atmosphere but no gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lever can work in zero-gravity conditions as long as the fulcrum and lever arm are physically attached.  They also work regardless of atmospheric presence.